# Prevent path based breadcrumb in theme, or, don't show breadcrumbs for 403/404 responses?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I am looking to do one of these solutions for a users 'contact' page. When a user has unchecked "Personal Contact Form", and someone accesses that URL (user/id/contact), the breadcrumb displays the users username in the breadcrumb.

The username in the breadcrumb is not desirable, because some people make their email address their username, so:

- How can I disable the breadcrumb from displaying on 403/404 responses, or
- How can I disable the path based breadcrumb service outright?

Comment: `How can I disable the path based breadcrumb service outright?` override the service with empty, I guess.

Comment: That's valid? Won't cause any errors?

Comment: Possibly... well... there is one way to find out, haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a visibility condition to the breadcrumb block. For 404 there is this module [block_in_page_not_found](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_in_page_not_found) and if you negate the condition the block is displayed on all pages other than 404's:

[image]

If you want to exclude 403 pages as well you can extend this module and add a check for

```
$status->getStatusCode() == 403
```

to Drupal\block_in_page_not_found\Plugin\Condition\PageNotFoundRequest::evaluate.

Or use the patch from this issue [Allow blocks to be configured to show/hide on 403/404 pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2245767), when it applies again.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I could do this too, that didn’t even occur to me.

Comment: Following their example I made a small module condition that checked 403.